# MATLAB Naive Bayes object storing

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

After using:

```
nb = NaiveBayes.fit(training, class)
```

To create a Naive Bayes classifier object, I want to save N-by-D of these objects in a matrix.
I have tried to do the following

```
ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES(2,3) = nb;
```

But I get: "Error using NaiveBayes/subsasgn (line 9)
The NaiveBayes class does not support subscripted assignments."

How would it be possible to fill a matrix of Naive Bayes classifiers in MATLAB?

Note that using fitNaiveBayes or fitcnb resuts in the same problem as they both return the same kind of object.

Thank you

Comment: try to use a cell array. initialize like this: `ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES = cell;` then use `ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES{2,3} = nb;`

Comment: ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES = cell; ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES(2,3) = cell; or even ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES{2,3} = cell; all give the error Error using cell. Not enough input arguments. Any thought?

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested my code. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a cell array.

First, initialize the cell array. If you now the numbers of elements you want to store, e.g. `N` x `D`, use

```
ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES = cell(N,D);
```

If you do not know the size beforehand, you can simply start with an empty cell array:

```
ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES = {};
```

Then if later you have generated your classifier object `nb` and you want to store it under the indices (2, 3), use

```
ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES{2,3} = nb;
```

To access that value later, use the same syntax `ARRAYOFNAIVEBAYES{2,3}`.

For more information, see Matlab's documentation of [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).